# jQuery selection issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, html-table

Ok, so I need to select a td and have it change the image inside it, which works fine. However, I need to be able to show the id of the td selected at the same time, but my function  has to select the image to change it. Is there a way doing both, so that onclich it selects the image, changes it, and then displays the alert with the td id in it? Code below

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("td img").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/d.gif');
    alert($(this).attr("td id"));
    return false;
  });
});
```

html

```
<div id='plan'>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td class='n' id='a1'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a2'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a3'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a4'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td></td>
   <td class='n' id='a6'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a7'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a8'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='a9'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class='n' id='b1'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b2'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b3'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b4'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td></td>
   <td class='n' id='b6'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b7'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b8'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='b9'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class='n' id='c1'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='c2'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='c3'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='c4'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td></td>
   <td class='n' id='c6'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='c7'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='C8'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='C9'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class='n' id='d1'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='d2'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='d3'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td class='n' id='d4'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
   <td></td>
  <td class='n' id='d6'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
  <td class='n' id='d7'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
  <td class='n' id='d8'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
  <td class='n' id='d9'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class='p' id='e1'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
  <td class='p' id='e2'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
  <td class='p' id='e3'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
  <td class='p' id='e4'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
  <td></td>
  <td class='p' id='e6'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
  <td class='p' id='e7'><img src='images/a.gif'/></td>
  <td class='p' id='e8'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
  <td class='p' id='e9'><img src='images/1.gif'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `$(this).parent().attr("id");`

Your code:

```
alert($(this).attr("td id"));
```

Is actually looking for an attribute named `td id` on the `img` tag.

Comment: yeah, my problem is that using this
    `alert($(this).attr("td id"));`

or this

  `alert($(this).attr("id"));`

selects the img tag, providing me with `undefined` as the output.

That's the answer that I'm looking for, thank you!